# God save the king

Tags: phrase-requests

What is the etymology for the phrase, “God save the king?”
All that I find is a trail back to the song.  Yet it seems to me that there must be an origin that goes back into the language.

Comment: "Well may we say, 'God save the Queen', because nothing will save the governor-general."  EG Whitlam 1975

Answer (score 4):

From the [Wikipedia page on this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_Save_the_Queen):

> The phrase "God Save the King" is much older than the song, appearing, for instance, several times in the King James Bible... 1st Book of Kings Chapter 1: verses 38–40, ... "And all the people rejoic'd, and said: God save the King! Long live the King! May the King live for ever, Amen"

The [King James Bible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_James_Version) is an English translation of the Christian Bible for the Church of England, begun in 1604 and completed as well as published in 1611 under the sponsorship of King James I of England.

Comment: There are other examples of something wished for being expressed as a command. "Long live the King!" (as in Rory's Bible passage) - "God bless America!" - "Down with America!" - "Have a nice day!"

Comment: Kate - all of those are much later than the King James Bible, so aren't answering the question...

Comment: Rory - I only meant that voicing a wish in that way is a natural form of expression, and not only in English. _Vivat Rex! Vive le roi!_

Comment: Where's the link?

Comment: there you go @Mari-LouA

Answer (score 4):

For this exact wording, it dates back to at least circa **1367**:

> Godde saue the kyng
>    <sub>[Eulogium Historiarum sive Temporis](https://books.google.com/books?id=IMaHyRAI-P0C&pg=PA87&lpg=PA87&dq="Godde+saue+the+kyng".)</sub>

For similar phrases, the Oxford English Dictionary has an earlier example from [The early South-English legendary; or, Lives of saints](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/c/cme/AHA2708.0001.001/1:3.18?rgn=div2;view=fulltext) (c1300):

> ‘Sire king,’ he seide, ‘god þe loke and saui þi dignite!’

Translation: *"Sire king," he said, "God look over you and save your dignity!"*

Comment: **loke** would not be simple present but subjunctive.  May God....

Comment: @TRomano So, arguably, is “God look over you”; it’s certainly not simple present. Semantically, it’s a third-person imperative, and those have always been expressed morphologically with the subjunctive in English.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet    It is a fervent wish, no?

Comment: @TRomano You can think of it like that, yes. Semantically, it’s difficult to draw a line between a wish and a command when the subject is a third-person entity. Is there really much semantic difference between “God have mercy on his soul” and “May God have mercy on his soul”?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet   To my way of thinking, commanding a third-person entity is the sound of one hand clapping.

Comment: @TRomano And yet third-person imperatives are a thing in many languages – morphologically, at least – but it can be difficult to really grasp the difference in meaning to an English speaker because they’re so tangled up in English. Irish is one language with a clear distinction between 3p subjunctive and imperative, but even there, it’s hard to say to what degree the imperative denotes a command. _Bíodh do chomhairle féin agat_ (lit. ‘be[3p] your advice own at-you’ = ‘have your own advice’ = ‘suit yourself/have it your way’) is imperative, but is that a command or a wish?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet:  That one hand is still clapping AFAIAC. Compare *fiat lux*. How can that which does not yet exist, **lux**, be commanded? To me it seems more an existential wish than a command.